# How to get the current time of TimeCircles Plugin in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the current time of TimeCircles,
when i use      `document.write($('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles().getTime());`
it will print the time that was set at the time it was instantiated.

How can I get the current time instead of the time it was set to when instantiated?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93ra0.png)

Comment: could you show more of your code sample so we have context of the issue?

Comment: <div id='CountDownTimer' data-timer='120' style='width: 400px; height: 250px;'>
 </div>

Comment: $('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }});

Comment: document.write($('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles().getTime());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles):

> To add a listener, use the `addEventListener(callback, type)` function. Callback is a function you pass to the event listener. The callback will then be triggered for each event. Three parameters are passed to your callback function, namely:

- unit: The time unit in string format. So, "Days"/"Hours"/"Minutes"/"Seconds".
- value: The new value of the time unit that changed. I.e.: 15.
- total: This is the total time left (or elapsed) since the zero point.

So just use:

```
$('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles().addEventListener(function(unit, value, total) {
    console.log(unit, value, total);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem, you'll need to call `getTime` in the `addListener` function that [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1024190/damien-fayol) is referring to.

Your HTML:

```
<div id='CountDownTimer' data-timer='120' style='width: 400px; height: 250px;'></div>

<div id='time'></div>
```

Your Javascript:

```
$('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }});

$('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles().addListener(function() {
  var time = $('#CountDownTimer').TimeCircles().getTime()
  $('#time').text(time)
});
```

Here, I am using `getTime` to fetch the current time and display it on the screen in a new div. I would stay away from `document.write` as that will try to write to the entire document.

See a working example: http://codepen.io/bomatson/pen/WrqOXg

I hope this helps!